# Unescaped Attribute Value XSS - how to sanitized event handlers in lightning aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, aura-attribute, url-encode

How do we sanitize variables/controller calls [`v.onRepeat`/`c.controllerCall`] used in `onclick`/`onchange` events as per SonarQube standards.

Here is the sample code :
**Issue 1** :
<lightning:buttonIcon tooltip="test"
alternativeText="test"
type="test"
iconName="test"
***onclick="{!v.onrepeat}"***>
</lightning:buttonIcon>

**Issue 2** :
<.. ***onclick="{!c.controllerCall}"***> .. </>

Can JSENCODE or HTMLENCODE be used?
how do we use them on variables/controllers here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't sanitize variables or controller calls. The Aura framework does this automatically for you. By the way, the onclick may not work as you expect, as you're trying to call an attribute (`v.`), not a controller function (`c.`).

Comment: yes I did read an article stating the same about aura framework handling, but upon running SONARQUBE on my code, these are some of the issues that were highlighted.    Also, as per this article "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_lightning_security.htm" 
this is an unsafe combination => any[tag] on* (event handler)[attribute]  js execution context[Issue]

Comment: @Dee Can you point out some specific messages? It's hard to imagine how any code scanner would identify errors in this code.

Comment: Yes this is the message -"Avoid unescaped/sanitized content in output"

Comment: @Dee It must be pointing to something else, or the scanner is broken. There's nothing in the code you posted that would trigger this in something like Checkmarx. Doublecheck and make sure it's not actually pointing to something else?

Comment: I'm doubly sure @sfdcfox. I have around 300 odd issues and most of them are pointing to that onchange/onclick event.. some point out variables some the controller call. Can we use JSENCODE/HTMLENCODE  or do you have any other suggestion for these issues ?

Comment: anything on this?